# Microwave stopped working/works again

Tags: equipment

I spilled coffee on my counter top and it went under my microwave.  It did not appear to me that it went inside the unit at all.  When I went to use it several hours later there was obviously a problem.  When I opened the door the microwave started working, turn table started going and light on.  I could still set the timer and use it but I did not.  This continued for approximately 24 hours.  It now appears that everything is back to normal but I am a bit worried to use it.  Is it safe to use?

Please help this frightened Grandma!

Comment: Give things a day to evaporate. Sounds like your door sensor micro-switch may have gotten damp.

Comment: There should not be any critical fragile electronics on the bottom, only 'crude' turntable motor circuitry so if you're feeling bold and brave, unplug the microwave, open the cover and clean everything near the spill area with denatured spirit / everclear. After letting it to evaporate and making sure no exposed electrical contacts are touching the casing reassemble and try. If you're not feeling that brave, just get a technician to look at it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about cooking.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the microwave malfunctioned clearly indicates that a damage is done. Judging based on symptoms that you're describing, this a typical short circuit. Now that things have dried up a bit, it might just keep working fine.

Chances are, corrosion caused by residue liquid will eventually destroy the circuit. But that's not the worst part.

Damage made to electric circuits by liquid can be unpredictable. By all safety standards and guidelines, your microwave is **not safe to use**. Fair enough, the chances that something really bad would happen are slim, but consequences can be brutal as well (think deadly electric shock or a fire). For your own safety, please, either find a technician and service your microwave, or buy a new one.